# How to match 0/1 coded values to a key provided in the same file, and rewrite as a line (instead of a list), in bash

Tags: bash, unix, sed

I have an input file, over 1,000,000 lines long which looks something like this:

```
G       A       0|0:2,0:2:3:0,3,32
G       A       0|1:2,0:2:3:0,3,32
G       C       1|1:0,1:1:3:32,3,0
C       G       1|1:0,1:1:3:32,3,0
A       G       1|0:0,1:1:3:39,3,0
```

For my purposes, everything after the first `:` in the third field is irrelevant (but I left it in as it'll affect the code).

The first field defines the values coded as `0` in the third, and the second field defines the values coded as `1`

So, for example:

`G       A       0|0` = `G|G`

`G       A       1|0` = `A|G`

`G       A       1|1` = `A|A`
etc.

I first need to decode the third field, and then convert it from a vertical list to a horizontal list of values, with the values before the `|` on one line, and the values after on a second line.

So the example at the top would look like this:

```
HAP0 GGCGG
HAP1 GACGA
```

I've been working in bash, but any other suggestions are welcome. I have a script which does the job - but it's incredibly slow and long-winded and I'm sure there's a better way.

```
echo "HAP0 " > output.txt
echo "HAP1 " >> output.txt

while IFS=$'\t' read -a array; do
        ref=${array[0]}
        alt=${array[1]}
        data=${array[2]}

        IFS=$':' read -a code <<< $data
        IFS=$'|' read -a hap <<< ${code[0]}

        if [[ "${hap[0]}" -eq 0 ]]; then
                sed -i "1s/$/${ref}/" output.txt
        elif [[ "${hap[0]}" -eq 1 ]]; then
                sed -i "1s/$/${alt}/" output.txt
        fi

        if [[ "${hap[1]}" -eq 0 ]]; then
                sed -i "2s/$/${ref}/" output.txt
        elif [[ "${hap[1]}" -eq 1 ]]; then
                sed -i "2s/$/${alt}/" output.txt
        fi
done < input.txt
```

Suggestions?

Comment: what `output.txt` for? show the final desired result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of running sed in a subshell, use parameter expansion.

```
#!/bin/bash
printf '%s ' HAP0 > tmp0
printf '%s ' HAP1 > tmp1


while read -a cols ; do
    indexes=${cols[2]}
    indexes=${indexes%%:*}
    idx0=${indexes%|*}
    idx1=${indexes#*|}
    printf '%s' ${cols[idx0]} >> tmp0
    printf '%s' ${cols[idx1]} >> tmp1
done < "$1"

cat tmp0
printf '\n'
cat tmp1
printf '\n'
rm tmp0 tmp1
```

The script creates two temporaty files, one contains the first line, the second file the second line.

Or, use Perl for even faster solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my @haps;
while (<>) {
    my @cols = split /[\s|:]+/, $_, 5;
    $haps[$_] .= $cols[ $cols[ $_ + 2 ] ] for 0, 1;
}
print "HAP$_ $haps[$_]\n" for 0, 1;
```